# Quick question about covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, connections

Let $f$ be a function and define $\nabla_X f = X(f)\,\,(1)$, where $\nabla$ is the connection on a manifold and as far as I understand the r.h.s is a function and $X$ is a vector field.

I am just a bit confused with the following statement: 'Since $\nabla_i f = \partial_i f, $ the covariant derivative of the covector $\nabla f$ is $\nabla_i \nabla_j f = \partial_i \partial_j f - \Gamma^k_{ji}\partial_k f$. But why is $\nabla f$ a covector. Isn't it a function from  eqn $(1)$? Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion it is not illustrative here to talk about covectors in this case but you can think of $\nabla f$ as a 1-form in the following sense: $\nabla f(X)=\nabla_Xf=X(f)$.

Comment: Actually, I am thinking $\nabla_i f$ denotes the $i$th component of the covector $\nabla f$ and these components are in general functions?

Comment: Yes, if you fix local coordinates you might indeed write $\nabla f=\partial_if\,\mathrm dx^i$. And the components are indeed smooth functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different things here, $ \nabla_X f $ and $ \nabla_i f $. The first has the coordinate-dependent expression $ X^i \nabla_i f $; this means that, as $X(f)$ is a scalar function, $\nabla_i f$ is a linear map from vectors to differentiable scalar functions, i.e. $T(M) \to C^{k}(M)$. Thus it is in the dual space of $T(M)$, $T^*(M)$, and these are covectors. Therefore $\nabla f$ is a covector.

Perhaps the easiest way of seeing this is to note that $X(f)$ is coordinate-independent, so a $(0,0)$-tensor. $X^i$ is a $(1,0)$-tensor, so by the quotient theorem, $\nabla_i f$ must be a $(0,1)$-tensor, i.e. a covector.

I hope that answers your question.